# Install XML Schema Definition Tool (xsd.exe) for VS 2017 Pro on Win 7

Tags: .net, xsd, windows-7, visual-studio-2017, xsd.exe

**Question:** How do I install xsd.exe for Visual Studio 2017 Professional on Windows 7?

**Attempt 1:**

According to the page [The XML Schema Definition Tool and XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/the-xml-schema-definition-tool-and-xml-serialization), xsd.exe is part of the Windows SDK. I have installed all components matching "Windows * SDK *" under Individual Components -> SDKs, libraries, and frameworks.

In the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, it still says: 'xsd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Which Individual Component of the Visual Studio Professional 2017 installer contains the XML Schema Definition Tool (xsd.exe)?

**Attempt 2**

I attempted to install [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). When I start the installer, I get the following warning:

> Windows SDK Setup
>
> Some components cannot be installed.
>
> Some Windows SDK components require the RTM .NET Framework 4. Setup
>   detected a pre-release version of the .NET Framework 4. If you
>   continue with Setup, these components will not be installed. If you
>   want to install these components, click Cancel, then install the .NET
>   Framework 4 from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187668 and
>   then rerun Setup.

The installer would not let me install anything under .NET Development.  I installed the .NET installer from the link, repaired, and rebooted. However, the Windows SDK installer still showed the same message.

Comment: I have the file here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.1 Tools\xsd.exe" so  make sure you have installed the .net 4.7.1 (SDK - Targetpack) in vs2017 installer

Comment: There it is!  There are three versions, each containing xsd.exe: `\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\ `, `\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools\ `, and `\bin\NETFX 4.7.1 Tools\ `. Version 4.6.1 was installed with VS2017 originally.  The other two were created yesterday (when I was installing things).  Make this an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: ok, so you also have .net 4.6.1 SDK installed. so you have it now.

Comment: add one folder to the PATH variable to see it in cmd.exe

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Make this an answer, and I'll upvote and accept

Comment: this is not worth posting it as answer here on stackoverflow (not really coding question). When I run the the dev prompt I can use xsd.exe. submit the issue to MS via IDE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017 maybe Microsoft can fix it in later 2017 update